# A More elegant way of doing this?

Tags: ruby

I keep saying to myself there must be a better way but I can't see it right now.. ideas?

```
i = 0; lose = 0; win = 0
while i < @array.size
  results = @array[i].results
  q = 0
  while q < results.size
    if results[q].to_i == 0 then
      lose += 1
    elsif results[q].to_i == 1 then
      win += 1
    else
      puts results[q]
      puts "false"
    end
    q += 1
  end
  i+=1
end
if win == lose then
  puts "true"
else
  puts "false"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array.each` instead of while loops.

You can use `array.count` instead of manually inspecting each array:

```
lose = results.count { |r| r.to_i == 0 }
win = results.count { |r| r.to_i == 1 }

# or possibly if the array can only contain wins and losses
win = results.count - lose
```

Comment: 1. Where is printing non-`0/1` elements? 2. `count` can be used without `select` 3. The initial array is not 1-dimensional.

Comment: Yes `count` is better than `select`. As for non 0/1 answers, I think the OP can figure that out. StackOverflow is for advice and direction, not for writing other people's code.

Comment: 17 lines reduced to 2. It's amazing what happens if you stop writing Fortran in Ruby syntax and start writing actual Ruby. I always thought that the "In Ruby you need 10x less code" claim was way overhyped, but when you see that *good* Ruby can be 10x shorter than *bad* Ruby, I wouldn't be surprized if the comparison with even less expressive languages would be even more favorable. I've certainly seen examples of a 100x reduction.

Comment: With a better object model, this could probably be reduced even further. For example, why are the numbers stored as strings and not as numbers? And why are they numbers *at all*, and not, say `GameResult` objects? E.g. `lose = results.map(&:to_i).count(&:zero?)`.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, coming from a Perl background I'm used to seeing things collapse down a lot when someone knows how to use `map` and `grep`, but it never gets 'zen-like'. Ruby does become zen-like, and that's what I really like about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = @array.flatten
puts (f.count('0') == f.count('1'))
puts f-%w{0 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you only have 0 and 1 in your arrays, you could in theory simply add up the values of all .to_i entries, then check if this value is exactly half of the total number of entries in your arrays.  Its hard to say if there's a better way of doing this without knowing more information.  Are win and lose counts used anywhere afterwards? Is this a function that returns right away or is this embedded in a larger function?  Are all your results array exactly the same size?  Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Splitting an array in two parts according to some test can be done using [Enumerable#partition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003130):

```
win, lose = results.partition {|r| r.to_i == 1}.map(&:size)
```